# How to brodcast custom messages using python-telegram-bot

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am new to Python. I want to broadcast a custom message to the users who registered my bot in a group or in private / personal.

How to do that function? Please help me - thank you

Answer (score 0):

basically, you'll have to keep track of all the user/chat_ids of the groups/chats you bot is a member in. Then for broadcasting, you'll have to iterate over all of them and send a message to each.
The bot API offers neither a functionality to send messages to a bunch of chat_ids at once nor to get all chat_ids where your bot is currently a member in.
In fact, we have some information about such use cases over [at the wiki](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-do-i-send-a-message-to-all-users-of-the-bot) of `python-telegram-bot`.
However, the logic is mainly implementation independent, i.e. you'd have to apply the same logic if you were to implement your bot with another python library or even a completely different programming language :)

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: I know php... And i have made that brodcast function in php ... In php? We have to collect the user ids or chat ids to a db after that use a command selection to send coustom messages to the chat ids... But I don't know what is the process to code in python.... Can you give me an example

Comment: I don't have any example code. But as I said, the general logic will be the same

Comment: I can help. what example do you need?

Comment: I need a example code of telegram coustom message brodcast using python-telegram-bot